# MySQL with two select statements and NOT IN

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to distract the following info from a booking system:

- select users whose products that either did not receive any paid bookings at all, or whose products did not receive any paid bookings in the last year;
- users can offer more than one product, and I only want to select users for whom these conditions apply over all their products.

I have two tables that contain the necessary info: a products table and a bookings table. The user without any bookings doesn't have a record in the bookings table; users with bookings should only be selected if all their products were booked longer than a year ago.

I have the following two statements, but I want to combine it and they don't give me the correct info (unfortunately I'm not very familiar with these difficult SQL statements):

Users without bookings (I think this one is correct):

```
SELECT products.user_id, products.id
FROM products
LEFT JOIN bookings
ON bookings.product_id = products.id
WHERE bookings.product_id IS NULL
```

Users that don't have any bookings over the last year (I select on status_paid, which has a datetime format)

```
SELECT DISTINCT bookings.user_id, DATE_FORMAT(bookings.status_paid, '%Y-%m-%d')
FROM bookings
WHERE bookings.user_id NOT IN (
    SELECT bookings.user_id
    FROM bookings
    WHERE DATE_FORMAT(bookings.status_paid, '%Y-%m-%d') > 
DATE_ADD(DATE_FORMAT(bookings.status_paid, '%Y-%m-%d'), INTERVAL -1 YEAR)
    )
AND bookings.status_paid IS NOT NULL
```

How can I combine them and make them to work?

Many thanks for helping me out!

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

if you need  a simple join you can use a left join between the two selects

```
   select t1.user_id, t1.id 
   from (
      SELECT products.user_id , products.id
      FROM products
      LEFT JOIN bookings
      ON bookings.product_id = products.id
      WHERE bookings.product_id IS NULL
   ) t1 
   left join (
    SELECT DISTINCT bookings.user_id, DATE_FORMAT(bookings.status_paid, '%Y-%m-%d')
    FROM bookings
    WHERE bookings.user_id NOT IN (
       SELECT bookings.user_id
        FROM bookings
        WHERE DATE_FORMAT(bookings.status_paid, '%Y-%m-%d') > 
      DATE_ADD(DATE_FORMAT(bookings.status_paid, '%Y-%m-%d'), INTERVAL -1 YEAR)
    )
  ) t2 on t1.user_id = t2.user_id
```